# Flash and SWFUpload I/O Error #2038 only on Chrome (flash bug or?)

Tags: flash, swfupload

I am using SWFUpload.  Here:

http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_unco/uploadtest.php

If you try to upload a file, Flash gives an Error #2038.  This error happens ONLY on Chrome.  It works fine in IE, Safari, Firefox, Opera.

I can confirm that the server is sending back a 200.  I can also confirm that the whole file has been transmitted. However, somehow in Chrome, flash is translating that to an IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,"Error #2038."  It works fine in every other browser that I have.  How can I stop this error from occurring?

Chrome Version:  24.0.1312.57 m

Operating System: Windows 7

Chrome Extensions: none

Flash Version: 11,5,31,139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Version: 11,5,31,139?? Sounds like you're using the built-in Chrome Flash plugin (called Pepper Flash) which has some bugs. Disable Pepper Flash and instead try the latest Adobe Flash plugin as installed from Adobe site.

Comment: That worked.  For any one else who is having this problem, you can install the newest flash version here ( http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ ) , then you have to type chrome:plugins into the Chrome address bar.  Click Details to the right of the flash plugin, you will have two versions of the flash player.  Leave the new one enabled, and disable the old one.

Comment: If've tried that, have both installed, but if I disable the chrome-flash and restart, it is automatically selected again.

Comment: @Remy Maybe this will help? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150596
Do you have the newest Chrome version?

Comment: We normally do have the newest Chrome version. But we had the issue on and off now. No idea what is going on...